# Uncaught ReferenceError: method is not defined js/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `main.js` file with a method in it:

```
;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
    'use strict';

    var testing = function(d) {
        //irrelevant code
    };

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

In my HTML, just before `</body>`, I have `jquery.js` referenced, and `main.js` right after it:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/main.js"></script>
```

and then an inline script which needs to call the `testing` function of `main.js`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        ( function($) {
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                var data = [];
                //..data is then populated and the function is called             
                testing(data);
        });
    } ) ( jQuery );
```

I get the following error on the line `testing(data);`

> Uncaught ReferenceError: testing is not defined

Why is this happening and how can I fix it? If my approach is wrong which is the correct one?

P.S. This is an ASP.NET MVC project

Comment: You need to learn about [variable scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Variable_scope), and subsequently [function scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Function_scope).

Comment: thanks, so is it not possible to access a variable from a different scope?

Comment: No, it's like trying to drink coffee from a mug that's located on another continent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `main.js` file is calling the anonymous function which defines your `testing` function in that scope. Once that function finishes, `testing` no longer exists.

So you have a couple choices.

1. Move `testing` into the global scope

   ```
   //main.js
   function testing(d) {
     //irrelevant code
   };
   ```
2. Move `testing` along with your other JS.

   ```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function($) {
        function testing() {
          ...
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
           // call testing here
        });
      })(jQuery);
    </script>
   ```

Comment: [`embedded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) would be the best terminology.

Comment: in your first example, do you mean that you moved the `testing` function after `})(jQuery, window, document);` ?

Comment: What you see is the entire file.

Comment: ah ok. it's not in a function so it becomes global. is it normal to have js files with either global or local scope, depending on your needs?

Comment: Well you can do it any way you want. The thing is to make your code easy to understand so if you look back at your project in a year, you'll know exactly where `testing` is and what it does instead of hunting .js files all over.